# File manager instances not showing among running processes

Tags: ps, process-management, thunar

I've over 10 windows of a file manager (Thunar, on Xubuntu Core 18.04) open, but `ps aux|grep thunar` shows nothing (except for the grepped string). Why? `ps -e` doesn't not show anything either.

EDIT: I suspect a reason may be that the location (in the address bar) in  those windows is an ejected external media. Another one may be that I didn't open the windows (they opened automatically when I plugged in the media), so the processes might not be mine. However, this still doesn't explain thunar not showing up. The problem persist after logout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunar used to use a capital 'T' in its name. The package for 18.04 has [both `Thunar` and `thunar` in it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/thunar/filelist). Try changing your `grep` command to ignore case:

`ps aux | grep -i thunar`

Comment: You were right. I find it very confusing (and a bug: if `thunar` maps to `[Tt]hunar`, it should do so system-wide)